# Is it possible to change a Yodlee user's email and loginName

Tags: php, yodlee

I am using the Yodlee API in my application.

I am currently looking into how to update user details on their end, once user updates his/hers details on my end.

Here is a link to the API: https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/user/updateUser

I don't understand how Yodlee matches the user and whether or not I can update the user's email address.

**UPDATE**

Also, can I update the user's `loginName`, since it, and the password, are used for logging in a user into Yodlee?

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee first asks the user to a login and then a userSession token will be created. 
And then with https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/user/updateUser API, the user can update their information.

You will not be able to edit the login name here.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik